# Reproducing random std::set<T*> order

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers

I have a test randomly failing, I suspect due to order of objects in a std::set ordered on pointers values.
However, on my current exe, the test always passes. Is there a way I can "mix" the pointers creations so the order of object in my set is different between two runs ?

In other words, is the "sorted order" (p1 < p2) of pointers deterministic for a given C++ code, or does different compilations or different runs can have different sorted orders ?

For example in this code, adding "p1b.reset(nullptr)" between p1 and p2 creation will invert p1 / p2 "sorted order" . Is there any other way to influence this order, without changing the source code ?

```
int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr< MyClass > p1b(new MyClass());

    //Lot of code, with memory allocated/deallocated

    std::unique_ptr< MyClass > p1(new MyClass());

    //p1b.reset(nullptr);

    //Lot of code, with memory allocated/deallocated

    std::unique_ptr< MyClass > p2(new MyClass());

    std::cout << "p1: " << p1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p2: " << p2.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Gives:

```
p1: 0x171c030
p2: 0x171c050
```

With "p1b.reset(nullptr)" commented out:

```
p1: 0x21f9030
p2: 0x21f9010
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Provide a working code snippet perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2**: based on your edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37027675/3

> In other words, is the "sorted order" (`p1 < p2`) of pointers
>   deterministic for a given C++ code, or does different compilations or
>   different runs can have different sorted orders ?

Yes, they can have different orders because - when you are allocating on heap, the "order of succession" of pointer addresses returned by the memory allocator is NOT guaranteed, so, yes, that can change anytime. Read the remaining part of the answer.

---

**EDIT 1**: based on your edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37027675/2

> For example in this code, adding `p1b.reset(nullptr)` between `p1` and
>   `p2` creation will invert `p1` / `p2` order. Is there any other way to
>   influence this order ?

No, it doesn't "invert" the creation order, you destroyed `p1` and created another object(perhaps equal) and had it take the place of `p1`.  Read the initial answer..

---

**Initial Answer**

> Is there a way I can "mix" the pointers creations so the order of
>   object in my set is different between two runs ?

Chances are that, your memory allocator allocates memory in a successive fashion, so if you allocate elements successively in a single threaded program, they will likely be in a succession of memory addresses. But if it is with regards to absolute pointer addresses, they will likely be at "different" absolute offsets on each run of your program due to [Address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

If you want the memory addresses of successive elements to be random, or in a specific order, you will have to create it in that random fashion or simply in the order you want it created...

*For a random fashion... ...Off the top of my head:* Perhaps, generate a `std::vector` of indices to the objects you want to create; randomize (or shuffle) the `vector` then run through the elements of the vector creating your objects.

---

My answer above is based on your stated suspicion. But again, I am uncomfortable with this:

> I have a test **randomly** failing, I suspect due to order of objects in a
>   std::set ordered on pointers values. However, **on my current exe, the
>   test always passes**.

Check for [Undefined Behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a) and also run memory tools and static analyzers through your code.

Comment: This is what I observe on a simple program. However, in my real life example I have different results for different compilations. I was wondering if I can dynamically influence this order to try to reproduce the different behaviors.

Comment: @MickaëlG, Ok... but can you post a minimal code snippet that explains what exactly you did, what are your results and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: About p1/p2 order: of  course it does not invert the creation order, but only the "sorted" order of p1 and p2. If the objects where added to a set, and the set iterated, p1 and p2 would have been inverted. Is the "sorted order" of pointers deterministic for a given C++ code, or does different compilations or different run can have different sorted orders ?

Comment: The "sorted order" is deterministic and guaranteed. most implementations implements `std::set` as a RB-tree ... I think your main problem is the `order` of creation of pointers: - and when you are allocating on heap, the "order" of pointer addresses returned by the memory allocator is NOT guaranteed, so, yes, that *can* change anytime

Comment: @WhiWTiM, "the order of pointer addresses returned by the memory allocator is NOT guaranteed, so, yes, that can change anytime" => Ok. So my question is: can I do something between two consecutive run to influence it and make it different than previous run.

Comment: @MickaëlG, Yes, Its easier for you to create the elements in a random fashion as described in my answer, doing that `will (randomize)` make it different from the previous run. However, you can write your own `T` specific memory allocator to allocate memory at random for you from a memory pool (using random locations in the pool)

Comment: The easiest way to randomize your set or map is to add a custom comparator. Have a `map<yourtype*, int> grmap`, populate with `(pointer, somerandomint)` pairs and use `grmap[pointer]` in the comparator.

Answer (score -2):

The order you allocate objects on heap is totally up to you. BTW, you do remember that `std::set` when destroyed only calls its contents destructors, which in case of pointers means pointers are simply not there, while the objects they pointed to remain in the heap and probably have become dangling references, right? If you store plain pointers in `std` containers do not forget to `delete` them manually.